# Visual Studio 2012 Windows phone game INVALID POINTER with Xna Game Studio 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I've done everything I've that was on the troubleshooting page. I don't have any VM's, I turned Hyper V off and on, my system is compatible. When I run the Emulator WVGA 512MB it will say "The Windows Phone OS is starting" and then never start. When I terminate the emulator it will say invalid pointer. I am only using the source code that is given with the XNA game.

Here's what it looks like after deployment https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw24F.png

How do I get the emulator to run I've been trying to get this work for 3 days now so any help would be great.